# Are GE THQP slimline breakers more susceptible to heat build up compared to a normal sized THQL breaker?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, heat

Should I be concerned at all about heat build up on a GE 50 amp THQP breaker I'm having installed for a 50 amp outlet?  My panel uses all THQP breakers except for the bottom two slots.  I only ask because I have one regular sized THQL 45 amp breaker in the bottom slot for my Air Handler/Heat Strip and wondered if the previous owner went with the larger, physical size breaker in that instance because of the higher amperage.  Otherwise the 50 amp THQPs are still sold at Home Depot and it's really the only spot I have left for a 2-pole to fit.  I included a picture to show the difference in size between the THQP and THQL 50 amp breakers.
[image]

Comment: Three related questions: 1 - Have you done a **load calculation** to determine if you have the capacity to add 50A? (Analogy: Just because you have checks in your checkbook (slots in your panel) doesn't mean you have money in the bank (available capacity in your service) This applies at both the service (entire utility supply) and, if this is not your main panel, panel size. 2 - Is this for an EV? Because if so there are reasons why it may make a lot of sense to install 20A or 30A rather than 50A (which can also help with load calculation issues...) 3 - What kind of wire are you using?

Comment: If this is for an EV and it's going to have an outlet, you may need to use the full-sized breaker because NEC 2017 and up require a GFCI breaker. You can get around the requirement by hard wiring. And yes, do a load calc.

Comment: The initial use is to plug in my nephew's RV as he will be visiting later this year for 2 - 3 weeks.  Electrician thinks I will be ok for total load capacity (single person, 150 amp service, single main panel) but of course that is not an official load capacity calc. I am opting for the Bryant 14-50 receptacle.  Will be all copper wire, 6 gauge.   I can't rule out an EV somewhere down the road.  I feel the RV will not draw too high of a continuous current.  However if I ever wanted to charge an EV, I don't think I'd feel comfy drawing more than 32 amps continuously and still sleep at night.